# trying to install rspec with bundler and rvm. error: undefined method 'spec'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, bundler, rvm

Rails 2.3.8, bundler 1.0.9.

I keep getting the error:

```
/Users/dwalseth/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p330@rails2/gems/bundler-1.0.9/lib/bundler/source.rb:72:in fetch': undefined methodspec' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from /Users/dwalseth/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p330@rails2/gems/bundler-1.0.9/lib/bundler/installer.rb:45:in run'
    from /Users/dwalseth/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p330@rails2/gems/bundler-1.0.9/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:ineach'
    from /Users/dwalseth/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p330@rails2/gems/bundler-1.0.9/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in each'
    from /Users/dwalseth/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p330@rails2/gems/bundler-1.0.9/lib/bundler/installer.rb:44:inrun'
    from /Users/dwalseth/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p330@rails2/gems/bundler-1.0.9/lib/bundler/installer.rb:8:in install'
    from /Users/dwalseth/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p330@rails2/gems/bundler-1.0.9/lib/bundler/cli.rb:225:ininstall'
    from /Users/dwalseth/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p330@rails2/gems/bundler-1.0.9/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in send'
    from /Users/dwalseth/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p330@rails2/gems/bundler-1.0.9/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:inrun'
    from /Users/dwalseth/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p330@rails2/gems/bundler-1.0.9/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:118:in invoke_task'
    from /Users/dwalseth/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p330@rails2/gems/bundler-1.0.9/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:246:indispatch'
    from /Users/dwalseth/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p330@rails2/gems/bundler-1.0.9/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:389:in start'
    from /Users/dwalseth/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p330@rails2/gems/bundler-1.0.9/bin/bundle:13
    from /Users/dwalseth/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p330@rails2/bin/bundle:19:inload'
    from /Users/dwalseth/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p330@rails2/bin/bundle:19
```

Here is my Gemfile:

```
Using json (1.4.6) 
  1 source :gemcutter
  2  gem "httpclient"
  3  gem "will_paginate"
  4  gem "money"
  5  gem "curb"
  6  gem "paperclip"
  7  gem "crack"
  8  gem "searchlogic"
  9  gem "authlogic"
 10  gem "sendgrid"
 11  gem "gemcutter"
 12  gem "taps"
 13  gem "rails", "2.3.8"
 14  gem "aws-s3"
 15  gem "sqlite3-ruby", :require => "sqlite3"
 16  gem "encoding-dot-com"
 17  gem "hoptoad_notifier"
 18 gem "chargify_api_ares"
 19

 20 group :development do
 21   gem "nifty-generators"
 22   gem "wirble"
 23   gem "hirb"
 24   gem "awesome_print", :require => "ap"
 25   gem "interactive_editor"
 26 end
 27 
 28 group :test do
 29   gem "rspec", "1.3.1"
 30   gem "rspec-rails", "1.3.3"
 31   gem "faker"
 32   gem "webrat"
 33   gem "cucumber"
 34   gem "cucumber-rails"
 35 end
```

Note, when I specify some other installation directory, e.g.

```
bundle install path/to/installation_directory
```

it installs the bundle fine.

I can't for the life of me figure it out!

Comment: What exact command is triggering this error?

Comment: Show us your `Gemfile` please.

Comment: This happens when running "bundle install"

Answer (score 1):

The latest rspec does not support Rails 2.3.8. You will need to load rspec version 1.3.1.

See http://cheat.errtheblog.com/s/rspec/ for details

Comment: I've got version 1.3.1 specified in my Gemfile

Comment: Did yo gem list --local to see what version of rspec and rspec-rails is installed?